# Delete and update Limit importance in mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance, limit, sql-delete

Presume I have a MySQL users table with several columns, of which one is the user id (there can't be a duplicate entry on that). When deleting or updating a particular row, should I use LIMIT 1, is that faster than no limit on delete and update querys?

So, is `DELETE FROM users WHERE id=123 LIMIT 1` faster than `DELETE FROM users WHERE id=123` ?

Same with update?

Answer (score 4):

There is no (and never was) benefit of `LIMIT 1` on PK updates/deletes. This makes your queries look weird (like, `user_id` is not PK).

You can prove my opinion by running `EXPLAIN ...` with and without `LIMIT 1`.

That's all only about PK and UNIQUE keys. In case of INDEX `LIMIT` may be huge optimization.